# React native redux after login statetoprops not updating before render

Tags: react-native, redux-form

After login and redirecting to Home page component here I am calling:

```
mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    getUser: state.userReducer.getUser
});
```

And trying to render the value:

```
render() {
    const {getUser: {userDetails}} = this.props;
    return(
      <View><Text>{userDetails.EmployeeID}</Text></View>
    )
}
```

USER Reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
```

const getUser = (state = {}, action) => {

```
switch (action.type) {

  case "GET_USER_LOADING":
      return {
        isLoading: true,
        isError: false,
        isSuccess: false,
        userDetails: null,
        errors: null
      }

  case "GET_USER_SUCCESS":
      return {
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        isSuccess: true,
        userDetails: action.payload,
        errors: null
      }

  case "GET_USER_FAIL":
      return {
        isLoading: false,
        isError: true,
        isSuccess: false,
        userDetails: null,
        errors: action.payload
      }

  default:
    return state;
}
```

}

export default combineReducers({
    getUser
});

And loginuser action

```
export const loginUser = (payload) => {
return async (dispatch) => {

    try {
      dispatch({
        type: "LOGIN_USER_LOADING"
      });
      const response = await fetchApi("front/authentication/login", "POST", payload, 200);

      if(response.responseBody.status) {
        dispatch({
            type: "LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS",
        });
        dispatch({
            type: "AUTH_USER_SUCCESS",
            token: response.token
        });
        dispatch({
            type: "GET_USER_SUCCESS",
            payload: response.responseBody.data
        });
        return response.responseBody.status;
      } else {
        throw response;
      }

    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: "LOGIN_USER_FAIL",
            payload: error.responseBody
        });
        return error;
    }
}
```

}

But getting an error:

> TypeError: Undefined is not an object(Evaluating 'userDetails.EmployeeID'

If I Remove the `userDetails.EmployeeID` and navigate to next page and then come back it show the `EmployeeID` fine.

Comment: What is the initial state of the `userReducer`? Can you post your `userReducer` as well?

Comment: Thanks i have updated the question with reducer and the loginuser action

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
render() {
const {getUser} = this.props;
return(
  <View><Text>{getUser.userDetails.EmployeeID}</Text></View>
)}
```

if that doesn't work, kindly post redux code

Comment: Thanks please check the updated question with reducer and loginuser action

Answer (score 0):

If your initial state resolves to something "falsy" for `userDetails` you can "wait" for its value:

```
render() {
    const {getUser: {userDetails}} = this.props;
    return <View>
        <Text>{userDetails ? userDetails.EmployeeID : 'Loading'}</Text>
    </View>
}
```